# Video Fill Container

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

Im trying to build a website in which the top container, being 100% tall and wide, will contain a background video with text over it.  How would I go about executing this video?  Thanks!

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501028/youtube-video-as-web-site-background?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

Now with HTML5 you can add video to your page with the `<video>` tag.

Be aware that HTML5's video tag is supported by all the major recent browsers, but you should always present an alternative for older browsers who don't support HTML5's video tag (and probably no HTML5 at all).

That being said, why don't you search the web for the keywords "html5 video background"? I just did it and I got loads of examples and tutorials! :)

Good luck!

Comment: It looks like he has no idea where to begin, so I gave him tips from where to look at.